# MYSQL I am trying to return a value where I need to compare one value against the minimum value for the same field when grouped against another field

Tags: mysql

Basically I am trying to calculate shots received in golf for various four balls, here is my data:-

```
DatePlayed  PlayerID    HCap    Groups  Hole01  Hole02  Hole03  Shots
----------------------------------------------------------------------    
2018-11-10  001          15       2       7        3    6   
2018-11-10  004          20       1       7        4    6   
2018-11-10  025          20       2       7        4    5   
2018-11-10  047          17       1       8        3    6   
2018-11-10  048          20       2       8        4    6   
2018-11-10  056          17       1       6        3    5   
2018-11-10  087          18       1       7        3    5
```

I want to retrieve the above lines with an additional column which is to be calculated depending on the value in the group column, which is the players (Handicap - (the lowest handicap in the group)) x .75

I can achieve it in a group by but need to aggregate everything, is there a way I can return the value as above?, here is query that returns the value:

```
SELECT 
    PlayerID, 
    MIN(Handicap),
    MIN(Hole01) AS Hole01,
    MIN(Hole02) AS Hole02,
    MIN(Hole03) AS Hole03,
    MIN(CourseID) AS CourseID, 
    Groups,
    ROUND(
        MIN((Handicap - 
            (SELECT MIN(Handicap) FROM Results AS t 
            WHERE DatePlayed='2018-11-10 00:00:00' AND t.Groups=Results.Groups)) *.75)) 
        AS Shots
FROM 
    Results 
WHERE 
    Results.DatePlayed='2018=11=10 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY 
    DatePlayed, Groups, PlayerID
```

.

```
  PlayerID MIN(Handicap)Hole01 Hole02 Hole03 CourseID Groups Shots
  -----------------------------------------------------------------     
      4        20         7       4     6       1        1    2
     47        17         8       3     6       1        1    0
     56        17         6       3     5       1        1    0
     87        18         7       3     5       1        1    1 
      1        15         7       3     6       1        2    0
     25        20         7       4     5       1        2    4
     48        20         8       4     6       1        2    4
```

Sorry about any formatting really couldn't see how to get my table in here, any help will be much appreciated, I am using the latest mysql from ubuntu 18.04

Comment: For the non-golfers would you like to publish your desired result? Also there are 18 holes in a typical golf course are you showing only 3 to simplify?

Comment: update your question and add  your expected  result

Comment: Thx for the formatting P. Salmon , how did you format? I have been googling but could not find the answer.

Comment: @mal highlight a block and ctrl-k or 4 spaces at the start of each line

Comment: Yes P. Salmon there will be 18 holes  I just simplified and rows will be returned by date, all lines returned will be golfers on the given date, anything from 3 ie one group to 20 ie 5 groups.

Comment: scaisEdge , my updated result would be to return the initial query containing a shots row as shown in my messy group by query. thx

Comment: That's not a way to work out the handicaps in four balls that I recognise - presumably there's some local rule in place. I am also unclear how player 001 who appears to be in groups 2 in the sample data gets to be in groups 1 in the end result.and why would his handicap change he is the lowest overall?

Comment: @P.Salmon thx for the update

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry the player column was not showing when I pasted my result field so I just manually added to the output, I will update this. The 3/4 handicap is for "skins" game where shots received are from lowest in your group.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. A database table is not a spreadsheet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Guys I have found the solution, basically I need to drop the MIN immediately after the ROUND of the equation and therefore it does not need a Group By.

> SELECT
>
> ```
> PlayerID,
>
> Handicap,
>
> Hole01,
>
> Hole02,
>
> Hole03,
>
> CourseID, 
>
> Groups,
>
> ROUND((Handicap - 
>
>       (SELECT MIN(Handicap) FROM Results AS t 
>
>        WHERE DatePlayed='2018-11-10 00:00:00'
>
>        AND t.Groups=Results.Groups)) 
>
>        *.75) AS Shots
> ```
>
> FROM
>
> ```
> Results
> ```
>
> WHERE
>
> ```
> Results.DatePlayed='2018=11=10 00:00:00'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer; too long for a comment...

First off, I happily know nothing about golf, so what follows might not be optimal, but it must, at least, be a step in the right direction...

A normalized schema might look something like this...

```
rounds
round_id DatePlayed  PlayerID HCap Groups  
       1 2018-11-10         1   15      2
       2 2018-11-10         4   20      1       

round_detail 
round_id hole shots
       1    1     7 
       1    2     3
       1    3     6
       2    1     7
       2    2     4
       2    3     6
```

Comment: thx for the input but not sure that will work as the main key is date played as multiple dates over multiple years . the groups field will change on every round as you do not play with the same people all the time. Each item in the table is unique to that game apart from date.

Comment: @mal The point is, this or something like this, is the correct approach to take. You wouldn't have separate columns for each hole unless you were some kind of masochist - but then again, if you like golf...